# Flutter: How to rotate diagonally a rect within a plane to paint

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have a word search app in which I use Rect to paint over a grid.

I have a gesture detector that allows me to identify which grid fields have been selected, through the global key and using onPanStart, onPanUpdate and onPanEnd I can see all the words that have been marked.

Everything works fine though, I don't know how to add a diagonal marker.

[I currently get this result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwOv3.jpg)

[I would like to implement this diagonal painting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwfZw.png)

[Demonstration of how the marking is currently, ps: The Gesture Detector still needs to be improved for painting, diagonally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnd6Q.jpg)

I tried to add the RotationTransition, but the behavior didn't look good, below.

```
RotationTransition(
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    turns: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation(45 / 360),
    child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
      child: DecoratedBox(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colorSelection!.withOpacity(0.4),
          border: Border.all(
            color: colorSelection!.withOpacity(0.1),
            //width: width,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

An overview of the important parts

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Stack(
  children: [
    GridView.count(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      childAspectRatio: letterWidth / letterHeight,
      crossAxisCount: nCols,
      children: puzzle.asMap().map(
            (index, letter) => MapEntry(
              index,
              BoardLetter(
                letter,
                isSelected: selection.contains(index),
                isHit: hitIndexes.contains(index),
                key: uniqueLetters[index]['key'],
              ),
            ),
          )
          .values
          .toList(),
    ),
    ...markers,
    Positioned(
      width: widget.width,
      height: widget.height,
      child: RotationTransition(
        turns: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation(360 / 360),
        child: GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          onPanStart: onPanStart,
          onPanEnd: onPanEnd,
          onPanUpdate: onPanUpdate,
        ),
      ),
    ),

  ],
);
```

Selection checks words and markers.last paints areas.

```
void onPanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
final currentIndex = computeLetterIndex(details.localPosition);

if(currentIndex >= 0 && currentIndex <= 99){

  final key = uniqueLetters[currentIndex]['key'];
  final RenderBox renderBox = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();

  print("render box size ${renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero, ancestor: context.findRenderObject())}");
  markerRect = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero, ancestor: context.findRenderObject()) & renderBox.size;

  List<int> _selection = [];
  if (checkSameRow(startIndex, currentIndex)) {

    if(direction == "horizontal"){
      markers.last = adjustedMarker(markers.last, markerRect!);
      _selection = genSelection(startIndex, currentIndex, 1);
    }

  } else if (checkSameCol(startIndex, currentIndex)) {
    //print("direction $direction");
    if(direction == "vertical"){

      markers.last = adjustedMarker(markers.last, markerRect!);
      _selection = genSelection(startIndex, currentIndex, nCols);
    }

  } else if (checkSameMainDiagonal(startIndex, currentIndex)) {
    markers.last = adjustedMarker(markers.last, markerRect!);
    _selection = genSelection(startIndex, currentIndex, nCols + 1);

  } else if (checkSameCounterDiagonal(startIndex, currentIndex)) {
    markers.last = adjustedMarker(markers.last, markerRect!);
    _selection = genSelection(startIndex, currentIndex, nCols - 1);
  }

  setState(() {
    selection = _selection;
  });


}
```

}

It is checked if a word was found, otherwise it removes the paint(markers.last)

```
void onPanEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
final word = selection
    .map((index) => puzzle[index])
    .fold("", (dynamic value, letter) => value + letter);

// Check if this is a valid word
var reversedWord = word.split('').reversed.join();
var wordIndex = widget.words
    .indexWhere((gameWord) => gameWord == word || gameWord == reversedWord);


if (wordIndex != -1) {
  print("word $word/$reversedWord was hit");
  widget.onHitWord(word, wordIndex);

  this.setState(() {
    direction = "";
    colorNumber = colorNumber + 1 ;
    hitIndexes = List.from(hitIndexes)..addAll(selection);
  });
}else{
  setState(() {
    direction = "";
    markers.removeLast();
    selection = [];
  });
}
```

}

The initial position is captured and marked.

```
void onPanStart(DragStartDetails details) {
startIndex = computeLetterIndex(details.localPosition);
final currentIndex = computeLetterIndex(details.localPosition);
final key = uniqueLetters[currentIndex]['key'];
final renderBox = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();

print(uniqueLetters[currentIndex]['letter']);
setState(() {
  markerRect = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero, ancestor: context.findRenderObject()) & renderBox.size;
  addMarker(markerRect, currentIndex);
});
```

}

The bookmark is added

```
void addMarker(Rect rect, int startIndex) {
markers.add(
    WordMarker(
  rect: rect,
  startIndex: startIndex,
  colorSelection: getColor(context),
  color: getColor(context),
));
```

}

Markers are adjusted with rect

```
WordMarker adjustedMarker(WordMarker originalMarker, Rect endRect) {
originalMarker.colorSelection = getColor(context);
originalMarker.copyWith(rect: originalMarker.rect!.inflate(20.0));

return originalMarker.copyWith(rect: originalMarker.rect!.expandToInclude(endRect));
```

}

Comment: Remembering, I can identify the word even diagonally, what I can't do is make the rect rotate in order to achieve the desired result in the "painting".

Comment: use a `CustomPaint` widget

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
At first I started building using canvas and CustomPaint, but it gave the user a lot of flexibility, so I started to use this approach with rects, which is very practical and satisfactory, except for the diagonal where I didn't identify how to implement it.

Do you tell me to apply CustomPaint to this solution? If yes, how would that be?

Comment: What looked bad about the rotation? Another option could be a ClipPath on a container.

Comment: I edited my question, with an image showing what the markup would look like.
1 - The marking is slightly off the diagonal.
2 - When I apply the rotation to change the angle, the gesture detector behaves strangely, not following the movement.

But my focus is on solving problem 1

In the image I changed the angle and dragged it to horizontal for demonstration: Although wrong, the desired would be to mark F -> V -> R -> M -> V

Comment: I can't open the link :/

Comment: I managed to open it, but this way I need to change the entire solution, correct?

Comment: Pskink, sorry for the delay. Your solution is great for me, I just need to make the painter become a list so that it doesn't keep erasing with each mark.

Comment: exactly, you need to pass two lists of `Offset` (or something similar) to `update` method - i tried to do that too but as i said i did not have much time ... also you need some checks that only horizontal, vertical and 45 degrees selections are possible

Comment: I've already put the checks locking on these angulations, it works fine. It only remains to add the list of paintings, I tried to pass the painter as a list, but the result was the same

Comment: I added the offset list pass, but currently it locks at initial position:
https://dartpad.dev/b961b00b079c86a16db8abd1a4915e93

Comment: Pskink, again thank you very much, your paint solution integrated very well into the word search and helped me a lot.
One last question, I noticed that the paint size is based on the width / qtd grid.

Is it possible to reduce the width of the painting so that the letters are closer?